# Mule SQL Server Data Source class type

Tags: mule

Any idea what class is "objectX"? Please see below code snippet.

```
<jdbc-ee:mssql-data-source name="sqlServerDataSource" user="yyy" 
         password="xxx" url="jdbc:sqlserver://xxxyyy.com;databaseName=testDB" 
         transactionIsolation="UNSPECIFIED" doc:name="MS SQL Data Source"/>

.
.
.

<scripting:component doc:name="Groovy">
            <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[

objectX = muleContext.getRegistry().lookupObject("sqlServerDataSource");
return objectX.getUrl();

]]></scripting:script>
```

The result of this is:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://xxxyyy.com;databaseName=testDB
```

After going through the entire Mule API doc, it seems to be [Class AbstractDataSourceFactoryBean ==> refer to Mule API](https://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/transport/jdbc/config/AbstractDataSourceFactoryBean.html). Am I correct?

Comment: You have object there, just ask it to print its class? :)

Comment: I got this from printing it: StandardDataSource:
     driver=<SQLServerDriver:3>
     url=<jdbc:sqlserver://... CoreDataSource :
     debug =<false>
     description =<null>
     login time out =<60>
     user =<mulesoft>
     verbose =<false> I'm not very familiar with Groovy. Can you give me an example to print its class. Thanks a lot.

Comment: can you do objectX.getClass().getName() or the groovy equivalent?

Comment: org.enhydra.jdbc.standard.StandardDataSource Awesome :) Thanks a lot Zavior. You helped me to confirm this.

Comment: Ill add it as an answer then, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark there, happy to help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have object there, just ask it to print its class, like so:

Something like

```
objectX.getClass().getName()
```